# Convert UIView co-ordinates from portrait to landscape and vice-versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, orientation

My iPad app allows the user to create UIViews and place them on the main view. So these views are created programmatically rather in xib files. It then remembers the co-ords of these UIViews. The user can then choose to show this collection of UIViews later.

```
----------------   ----------------
|Collection 1 >| > |          |   |  
|Collection 2  |   | View A   |   |
|Collection 3  |   |          |   |
|              |   |--------------|
|              |   |     |        |
|              |   |     | View B |
|              |   |     |        |
----------------   ----------------
```

So, above you can see that `Collection 1` has been selected.

Now, the app should be usable in both landscape and portrait. So if a view is created in portrait, and then displayed in landscape how could I handle the co-ords? And vice-versa? And even when views are being created.

In my case I want UIViews to adjust proportionally, and if the views abut each other in one orientation, then they should also abut in the other orientation. So the above becomes this in landscape:

```
----------------   ------------------
|Collection 1 >| > |          |     |  
|Collection 2  |   | View A   |     |
|Collection 3  |   |----------------|  
|              |   |     | View B   |
|              |   |     |          |
|              |   ------------------  
|              |    
----------------
```

I guess part of what I'm asking is: Is there a way of obtaining what the co-ords would be in the other orientation without actually rotating?

Comment: Are you planning on using autolayout? The approach for the view layout will vary depending on whether you are or not.

Comment: I'm happy to use autolayout, but in my experience it can be rather difficult to untangle

Comment: In which case, auto resizing masks are going to be your answer. I think somebody's already sent you along that way :)

Comment: I think you're right, but when the views are created in landscape, how to do I recreate those views in portrait afterwards?

Comment: Autoresizing will adjust the size of your views when changing orientation either way. If you need to reproduce the same size later, then immediately after resizing (probably a hook called something like `didFinishAutorotating`) examine the value of the frame property of the subviews and store them in variables for later.

Comment: There won't be a chance to examine views after `didFinishAutorotating` since this view controller may not be the current screen. For instance, the view controller is presented (blank) in landscape. Views are created on the main view. Then the viewcontroller is dismissed (popped back to the previous view controller) and removed from memory. Now the device is rotated, and the collection of views is selected again. How to get the correct co-ords in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set autoresizing masks. Like view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight

EDIT: I have just realized, I forgot about the case for view b.

For main view you need set : `UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight`

For view A : `UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight`

Since height of view A will be decreased, view B has to move up. We need to set flexible top margin mask.

For view B : `UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`

While giving that autoresizing masks I assumed you placed the views top relative. It means you have set frames either just a value like 10.0 or relative to element of which is placed above the view it selfs, like `viewB.frame = CGRectMake(xCoordinate, viewA.frame.origin.y + viewA.frame.size.height, width, height)`

It wont work if you have them bottom relative like `viewB.frame = CGRectMake(xCoordinate, mainView.frame.size.height - 200.0, width, height)`

Comment: you mean for the main view, or sub-views? can't get this to work

Comment: In your case all of them. Your main view will be resized because the size of window has changed. And subviews will be resized because the size of main view has changed. Optionally you can set autoresizingMasks for subviews of subviews differently

Comment: Please note that the frames you set are for portrait orientation. The autoresizingMask change the frames when you go landscape mode. So while programming and setting frames just think for portrait orientation and autoresizingMask will change them proportionally for you and depends how you set them. You find the possibilities here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html and of course you can combine them.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn "on" *all* the resizing masks, for the subviews (View A and View B).

```
viewA.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
                         UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

If you do that, then all the edges of the views will keep their location as a proportion of the parent view's space. E.g., View A's frame can be thought of as (left, top, width, height) = (0%, 0%, 80%, 50%) and View B's as (40%, 50%, 60%, 50%). When you rotate the views' bottom and top are still at 50%, though that's numerically a different value. View A's left and top still abut the edge of the parent view. Even though those margins are flexible, they won't change if the margin is zero. Same for B's right and bottom edges.

Answer (score 0):

You can move out the logic to deal with coords in a separate method and call this method in `usingShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` or `shouldAutorotate` dependently on ios version